# How to access local rest api in my android device?

Tags: android, rest

I have created fake rest api locally. I can access json data at http://localhost:3000/db in my PC.If I am using same url in android code ,I am not getting data. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811789/android-connection-to-localhost

Comment: I tried this but it is not working

Comment: To help you to solve this problem you should share some code to us

Comment: protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            studentList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

Comment: I am using url="http://192.168.1.105:3000/db

Comment: Both PC and android device is on same network

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236716/locally-call-restful-web-service-generated-by-netbeans-ide-from-android?rq=1

Comment: When I am using another laptop ,I am able to access the rest api in my device. Could you please tell me how to bypass the proxy(I am using my office laptop)?