# retrofit 2 404 not found

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to use retrofit but i get 404 code and message "not found"

Response `{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found}`

i can see on my server log that the request was successfully and the response is and object

I used to parsed it with Gson

```
{
  "codigoRespuesta": "00",
  "descRespuesta": "Success",
  "token": "0bc6e8a352a002db5782ae729501fd05bd825cf165864a0ab32d1ab1529001ed2583df4a5ab257a30f97117ec0fec0b6df60adf288fd6b1579f31d2d636d9aa"
}
```

so I'm using the same object with retrofit that i used to use with asyncs request

```
public class AuthenticationResponse extends Response {
private String token;

public AuthenticationResponse() {
}

public AuthenticationResponse(String codigoRespuesta, String descRespuesta) {
    super(codigoRespuesta, descRespuesta);
}

public AuthenticationResponse(String codigoRespuesta, String descRespuesta, String token) {
    super(codigoRespuesta, descRespuesta);
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken() {
    return this.token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String toString() {
    return "AuthenticationResponse{token=" + this.token + ", " + super.toString() + '}';
}
```

}

```
@XmlRootElement

public class Response {
private String codigoRespuesta;
private String descRespuesta;

public Response() {
}

public Response(String codigoRespuesta, String descRespuesta) {
    this.codigoRespuesta = codigoRespuesta;
    this.descRespuesta = descRespuesta;
}

@XmlElement
public String getCodigoRespuesta() {
    return this.codigoRespuesta;
}

public void setCodigoRespuesta(String codigoRespuesta) {
    this.codigoRespuesta = codigoRespuesta;
}

@XmlElement
public String getDescRespuesta() {
    return this.descRespuesta;
}

public void setDescRespuesta(String descRespuesta) {
    this.descRespuesta = descRespuesta;
}

public String toString() {
    return "codigoRespuesta=" + this.codigoRespuesta + ", descRespuesta=" + this.descRespuesta;
}
```

}

This projects is based on this example
[github project](https://github.com/TutorialesHackro/AndroidTutorials/tree/master/%23AndroidTutorials_Retrofit)

My retrofit interface

```
public interface servicesTutorial {

@GET("usersFake")
Call<List<ResponseService>> getUsersGet();


@POST("usersFake")
Call<List<ResponseService>> getUsersPost();

@POST("login")
Call<AuthenticationResponse> doLogin(@Body RequestLogin request);
```

}

My MainActivity class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        final String url = "https://myurl.com/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();


        servicesTutorial serviceTuto = retrofit.create(servicesTutorial.class);

        Call<AuthenticationResponse> call2 = serviceTuto.doLogin(new RequestLogin("user","pwd"));

        call2.enqueue(new Callback<AuthenticationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AuthenticationResponse> call, Response<AuthenticationResponse> response) {
                Log.e("testing", "respuesta: "+response.message()+" *** "+response.code()+" *** "+response.isSuccessful() +
                        " *** " + response.raw().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AuthenticationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("testing",t.toString());
            }
        });


}
}
```

---

**EDIT:
I finally got it, appareantly because my services was made with Java and Spring I had to add a header to my request ("Accept: application/json")**

Comment: please, show the code the retrofit 2

Comment: actually is your github project bro LOL, i'm trying to use my own service but i get a null object on my response (the server is sending a response)

Comment: hahaha dude i 'am creator the this repo XD haha you use emulator?

Comment: Told you XD yah I use emulator and my android device

Comment: you service rest is local?

Answer (score 0):

Posible solutions

1: if your service is [local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257266/how-to-access-localhost-from-a-genymotion-android-emulator/34504649#34504649),remember use

**Genymotion**

http://10.0.3.2/

**Default AVD**

http://10.0.2.2/

2: Check  if your endpoints are corrects

```
usersFake
login
```

3:In my case in my local i have nginx and i have a problem accessing using emulator

Comment: My service is not local is posted on Internet, my endpoints are correct actually I reach my WS but my response is null on retrofit callback  (on server log <WS> I see the whole process with a valid response) :(

Comment: maybe your json responde no it's correct, please verify using this pages http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/    ----  http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Is the same service that I actually use, I already have an app developed with all this classes and services but now I want to move it to clean architecture I used to do my calls to my client with an http client and then parse it with gson I'm using the same, it can't be the object or the json (the json is on the post) that why I don't understand what's going on :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue yesterday. Try this:

Check your working URL in browser. If your url endpoint has any extensions like `.php`, then add it in your `GET/POST` annotation parameter and write the fullname like `@GET("userFake.php")`.

This worked for me. Hoping it also works for you.

Comment: Hello, my service is a java service, the endpoint is ok I can see the request on server side I can see the response on server side but retrofit gets a null response :(

Comment: First of all use Postman for checking issue generated from mobile /tvs?

Answer (score 0):

While change in BASE URl ,it works for me.Change your BaseUrl Like this:

```
  private static final String BASE_URL="http://abcd.com/abcd/index.php/";
```

And Make endpoints like this

```
@GET("api/Abcd_controller/users")
    Call<ABCDList>getUsers();
```

For more details see this [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1303).
This work for me .Hope this will also work for you. Thanks