# access localhost from a Genymotion android emulator?

Tags: android, web-services, genymotion

I know this type of question asked before,but my problem still exist.
I have written wcf web service on visual studio and when run it ,it is running on IIS express and give to me this address "**http://localhost:63048/Service1.svc**" for my service address. when i put this address to my android code

```
new SetUserFromServerToRv(this).execute("http://localhost:63048/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery");
```

and run it i got this error on debug my code:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 63048) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I had searched on google and this site and find some solution. according this solution I changed my localhost ip to this: **10.0.3.2** but also i got the same error. according some opinion i change my localhost to  **Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network ip** but i got same error.
i run this command on my windows:

```
C:\Users\sayres>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : x::x:x:x:x%18
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : x::x:x:x:x%4
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.154.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : x::x:x:x:x%15
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.137
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : x.x.x.x

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

even I put vbox ip on my Asynctask code like this:

```
new SetUserFromServerToRv(this).execute("http://192.168.56.1/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery");
```

but i got same error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 80) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

By postman i access to my server by this address:

```
http://localhost:63048/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery
```

and i do not have any problem.
In addition I have standalone computer and i connect to internet by **USB tethering** on mobile phone.

what's your idea??

************Edit***************

As i mention above I have 3 **Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network** and **Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2** and **Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2**. I put these 3 IP on these interfaces into my code and nothing of these IP's works.

Comment: please remeber in Emulator its diferents,see this answerd https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504649/3741698

Comment: @DavidHackro I've read this post and it is not work for me!!

Comment: @Robert I used 10.0.2.2 and http://10.0.3.2/ but i got error.

Comment: I have used **http://192.168.56.1:63048** but don't work like other.