# How to access WIFI server in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, wifi, emulation, genymotion

I want to connect android device to WIFI server. I can do it in AVD and real device with success, but can't give any result in Genymotion. I use 192.168.1.100 for server.

[Access host from Genymotion emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463319/access-host-from-genymotion-emulator)

In this link somebody said try 10.0.3.2 and i did it but the result not changed and still can't access server in Genymotion.

Comment: thats localhost means incase php script runs on pc u cann access the url via 10.0....

Comment: my server is a hardware wifi that i want to send data and recieve. there is no url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your computer ip adress.

Open cmd and write ipconfig and try IPv4 adress.

I hope it will work.

Comment: in ipconfig virtualbox's ip is 192.168.56.101. so i changed server ip to 192.168.56.50 and give result in AVD, but still nothing in Genymotion.