# Access example.com from Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, genymotion

I am developing an hybrid application using ionic. I use [Ionic Box](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-box) which is ran by vagrant (Virtual Box). I also use Genymotion as the emulator.

In my application, I authenticate using Google OAuth2. The configuration needs a redirect url callback which is setup to `http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback` for the development environment. If I setup an IP address I get the following error: [Error: invalid_request device_id and device_name are required for private IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip)

In genymotion browser, I can access my application with `http://10.0.3.2:8100`. So I would like to be able to access `http://10.0.3.2:8100` when typing `http://www.example.com:8100`.
[Access host from Genymotion emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463319/access-host-from-genymotion-emulator)

How do create that mapping in Genymotion?

Vagrant Box:

```
vagrant@ionic-android:/project$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f9:58:8e
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef9:588e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2459 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:196630 (196.6 KB)  TX bytes:4896919 (4.8 MB)
```

Genymotion Emulation is running on `192.168.56.101`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add an entry in `/etc/hosts`.

## Get the hosts file on your local system

```
vagrant@ionic-android:/project$ adb pull /system/etc/hosts
```

## Add an entry to that file

```
192.168.0.1 www.example.com
```

## Remount /system as writable in case it's read only

```
vagrant@ionic-android:/project$ adb shell
root@vbox86p:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@vbox86p:/ # exit
```

[Read only file system on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android)

## Push the modified hosts file

```
vagrant@ionic-android:/project$ adb push hosts /system/etc
```