# Google Chrome browser in Android 12 emulator doesn't load any webpages (internet is working!)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, android-12

I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 2, on Windows 10 and I'm running an Android 12 emulator.

I'm attempting to simply load any webpage using Google Chrome, however all that happens is that the progress bar appears, but nothing ever loads regardless of the website that I try to load. The other thing that happens is that sometimes Chrome just sits on the loading screen itself and doesn't finish loading when started.

I've verified that the emulator has internet access, and in fact I can get webpages to load using the Webview Browser Tester app that is present in the emulator by default.

Stumped with this one, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In Android 12 - API 31 emulator, the Chrome screen gets frozen during launch up, though the Webview browser is working. Could you please let me know if you have found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no solution found as yet.

Comment: It could be too late but we fixed it by just upgarding the version of webview

Comment: Have same issue: browser shows results but can't show any site. Installed Firefox and all is ok.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It's caused by vulkan. To fix it, you must turn vulkan off on emulator or chrome.

```
# Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

If you want to use both vukan and chrome on emulator, just mark vulkan flag as disabled in chrome://flags and re-enable Vulkan on emulator by changing `Vulkan` value to on or deleting `advancedFeatures.ini`.

Comment: An reason for why Vulcan isn't turn off by default on Emulator ?

Comment: take care while saving file to save it as .ini not as normal .txt. this wasted my time hope saves other's time.

Comment: The path in Windows 10 is: `C:\Users\%username%\.android`

Comment: This solution works on Android 13 (API 33) as well (the problem obviously exists there too).

Comment: until now google didn't fix the issue

Comment: KUbuntu 22.10 Android-Studio Dolphin just had this bug and nuking Vulkan totally work. WTF is "Vulkan"??

Comment: After quite a while searching for a resolution for this issue, this pretty much solved it. Thanks. API 33

Comment: This seems working also on Linux for Emulator version 32. For an alternative see also: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting#cannot-open

Comment: It works for API 34. Only this approach was helpfull for me. So, there wasn't any necessity to dive into the network, firewall, wifi and other settings.

Comment: It's January 2024 and the problem still persists. Your solution worked for me, API33.

Answer (score 45):

This helped me to resolve my issue with Android 12 doesn't load any webpages. I'm using Android studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 on Windows 10 and I'm running Android 12 emulator with API31.
What I did:

1. Closed an emulator
2. In a text editor (e.g Notepad++) I pasted these two lines.

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

3. I saved the file as `advancedFeatures.ini` -> you can directly save it in `.android file` or wherever you want and then move it to `.android` file.

```
 Path example: C:/Users/your user name/.android
```

4. Started an emulator

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I solved my problem too. My problem occurs after configuring API31 and above. All versions below API30 I had no troubles. Creating a file advanceFeatures.ini and save it in the .android folder after closing all emulators it start working with API31.

Comment: This fixed the problem on API 34 emulator.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible, to set the emulated Graphics Performance to "Software - GLES2.0" in the Virtual Device Configuration.

Comment: This approach also works in lieu of the first two answers setting Vulkan=off and GLDirectMem=on. However, you would need to do this for all emulators. The advancedFeatures.ini approach will be applied to all emulators. Both solutions are valid to me.

Comment: This was good enough for me to launch chrome, then use the feature flag answer to disable vulkan, then turn the graphics back to hardware.

Comment: While this works, for me, it also slowed down the emulator significantly.

Answer (score 4):

Create **advanceFeatures.ini** file with content:

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

path of this file should be:

```
MAC: (/Users/"yourUser"/.android)
WIN 10: (C:\Users\"yourUser"\.android)
```

on android make sure you create a device that has playstore option(sign) and uses "Software-GLE 2.0" in Emulated performance:Graphics
(might be needed that you actually log in in playstore via emulator to update emulator chrome version)

**might be needed**:
switching camera options to 'None'

inside .android folder(can refer to paths above) check /avd/"emulatorName/config.ini"

```
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=software
```

If you want to open link directly

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://your.url.here"
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, its the camera lock on the laptop. Temporarily unlocking it finishes the initialisation of Chrome. I could not find where to switch the camera option to none.

Comment: when you create a new Android Virtual Device , just when you create the name of that AVD you have "Camera" some sections below the name

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to resolve this issue, without editing an INI file, is to start the emulator from the command line and add -feature -Vulkan as one of the parameters.