# Why can't I use Chrome webpages on my android emulator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux, android-emulator

Why does my emulator screen look like gibberish? [image: Gibberish]

The emulator works fine, but when I try to visit any webpage on chrome using the emulator, it crashes as you can see.

I don't know where else to look, and I need to get this up and running soon, so I can contribute to my companies repository.

I'm hoping somebody with more experience may have had issues with this and experience handling it.

Note: I had to enable SVM and IOMMU in my BIOS to even get the emulator to start on windows. All because I'm using a Ryzen 5 processor.

Also there are no windows options to enable hyper-v.

Thanks in advance!

-Allen

Comment: Same issue man. Can't seem to find a fix so far

Comment: might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134922/google-chrome-browser-in-android-12-emulator-doesnt-load-any-webpages-internet

Answer (score 0):

The link in comment is right - this issue is because of vulcan.
I solved it as described - created a file `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` with following content:

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

And then restarted the emulator