# Android 12 facebook login stuck in black screen

Tags: java, android-studio, facebook-login

I'm trying use facebook login in API level 31, but every times I press my login button try to go to facebook login page, it just stuck in black screen like this [stuck in black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZdKT.png) ,and there is not show any exception or error, I also try use lower API and work fine. How can I solve this problem?

edit:My other button that open external browser also fail to open in API level 31.

Answer (score 0):

It seems android 12 problem when using emulator open chrome.
Reference to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134922/google-chrome-browser-in-android-12-emulator-doesnt-load-any-webpages-internet` to solve this problem.